# What is the maximum integer allowed in a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is JavaScript's Max Int? What's the highest Integer value a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)

What is the maximum integer in javascript? I have a variable that starts in 0 and adds 100 each 0.1 seconds. What is the maximum number it can reach?

BTW, I thought this question had been answered before but I couldn't find it. If it is answered, please send me a link to it =) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript numbers are IEE 794 floating point double-precision values.  There's a 53-bit mantissa (from memory), so that's pretty much the limit.

Now there are times when JavaScript semantics call for numbers to be cast to a 32-bit integer value, like array indexing and bitwise operators.

Answer (score 2):

A javascript variable can have any value you like. If native support isn't sufficient, there are various libraries that provide support for unlimited precision arithmetic (e.g. [BigInt.js](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html)).

The largest value for the [ECMAScript Number Type](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19) is +ve infinity (but infinity isn't a number, it's a concept). The largest numeric value is given by Number.MAX_VALUE, which is just the maximum value representable by an [IEEE 754 64-bit double-precision number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format).

Some quirks:

```
var x = Number.MAX_VALUE;
var y = x - 1;
var z = x - 2;

x == y; // true
x == z; // false
```

The range of contiguous integers representable in ECMAScript is from -2^53 to +2^53. The largest exponent is 2^1023.

Answer (score 1):

It is `1.7976931348623157e+308`

to try it yourself code it

CODE

```
alert(Number.MAX_VALUE);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XHcZx/

Comment: That's not what was asked, I don't think. The question explicitly says **integer**, and I suspect that means the OP is interested in the ability to represent a continuous sequence of integers. If you subtract 1 from that value, you won't really get that number minus 1.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I wasn't aware of the Number.MAX_VALUE property, which in fact shows what is supposed to be the largest possible number in javascript.

Comment: @jpatiaga you should be clear in your question - the words **integer** and **number** mean different things!

Comment: (Though admittedly, that value is an integer :-)

Comment: According to [ECMA-262 §15.7.3.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.3.2), that is an **approximation** of the `largest positive finite value of the Number type`. You can't construct a continuous sequence of numbers from zero, e.g. `Number.MAX_VALUE - 1 == Number.MAX_VALUE // true`.

Comment: @Pointy you're right. I needed to know about **integers**, so Number.MAX_VALUE is not the right answer.